# Switch statement: Why can't I have the same variable name in different cases? Java

Tags: java, duplicates, switch-statement

I still writing the code, and it doesn't make a very big difference in a project like mine, but if I was to make something bigger, it would be a pain. here it is:

```
        case 0:
            System.out.print("Insert the N: ");
            double N = in.nextDouble();
            double mol = N / Na;
            System.out.print("There are " + mol + " mol in that sample");
            break;

        case 1:
            System.out.print("Insert the m: ");
            double m = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Insert the M: ");
            double M = in.nextDouble();
            double mol = m / M;
            System.out.print("There are " + mol + " mol in that sample");
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.print("Insert the V: ");
            double V = in.nextDouble();
            double mol = V / Vm;
            System.out.print("There are " + mol + " mol in that sample");
            break;
```

The first "mol" has no problem, but in case 1 and case 2, it says "Duplicate local variable mol". If I use the If statement it works. Is Java just like this or there is a way around it?

Thanks

Comment: I think I just solved it using { and } between each case.

Comment: If statements are different blocks. In your example is only one block.

Comment: You should generally declare local variables outside the scope of a `switch` clause.

Comment: If you find yourself really wanting to do that, it probably suggests that you need to break the method up into individual methods that are called from the cases. Otherwise, declare your variables at the top of the method.

Comment: In case you are wondering, it is because in Java (like C/C++) everything inside the switch's braces are part of the same stack frame with the case labels being just that - labels (like you'd use with a goto statement in C/C++). Therefore all variable names have to be unique. Adding the braces to each case statement creates a new stack frame, however, enabling free choice of variable naming.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's because a `case` doesn't create a scope. So, both the variables in the 2 cases are in the same scope. If you want to do this, you can add braces for each case, which will create a new scope for each case.

```
    case 0: {
        System.out.print("Insert the N: ");
        double N = in.nextDouble();
        double mol = N / Na;
        System.out.print("There are " + mol + " mol in that sample");
        break; 
    }

    case 1: {
        System.out.print("Insert the m: ");
        double m = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Insert the M: ");
        double M = in.nextDouble();
        double mol = m / M;
        System.out.print("There are " + mol + " mol in that sample");
        break;
    }
```

But, ideally there is no need to declare a separate local variable for each case. If you are using a variable in all the cases, that clearly signifies that variable to be declared directly inside the `switch` statement:

```
switch (someVar) {
    double mol = 0.0;

    case 0: mol = n / Na;
            break;

    case 1: mol = m / M;
            break;
}
```

P.S.: Can I advice you to name your variables something apart from english alphabets - `n`, `M`, `N`?

Comment: You certainly *can* do that, so +1, but it would be third on my list: 1. If there's enough code that I feel like I have to have the variables close to where they're used, the cases should be their own methods called from the cases. 2. If not, declare the common variables at the top of the method containing the `switch`. 3. (And a very distant third) this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually, I myself don't even remember the last time I used such workarounds in Java. This should really be avoided :)

Comment: @RohitJain: I figured you were just being thorough. :-)

Comment: Can confirm, this solution works in Javascript as well :D

Answer (score 4):

Because those variables are there in `single block` may be you would have written this `switch` statement in some `method`.
In a single method you can't have dup variables.